# how to work with air 3.2 and HTMLLoader?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

i use this code to view my web page .... it is work with air 3.2 for desktop ... how to make it work with air 3.2 for android ? .... it does not loading anything , only white screen !

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.html.HTMLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

public class HTMLLoaderExample extends Sprite
{
    public function HTMLLoaderExample()
    {
        var html:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
        var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.doomanco.com/");
        html.width = stage.stageWidth;
        html.height = stage.stageHeight;
        html.load(urlReq); 
        addChild(html);
        html.x = 0;
        html.y = 0;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Adobe said about `HTMLLoader`: *" AIR profile support: This feature is supported on all desktop operating systems, but is not supported on mobile devices or on AIR for TV devices. You can test for support at run time using the HTMLLoader.isSupported property. See AIR Profile Support for more information regarding API support across multiple profiles. "*, I think that's not supported for your android device, you ca verify that using `HTMLLoader.isSupported` property. For more details you can take a look here : [Adobe.com : HTMLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html) and here : [Adobe.com : Device profiles for AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS144092a96ffef7cc16ddeea2126bb46b82f-8000.html).

Comment: thanx .... but by the way how to do this .. icon in the android phone only open my website ?

Comment: I don't know what do you want to do exactly, if just open your site in the browser you can use `navigateToURL`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks dude @DodgerThud & @akmozo ..... it is done with this:

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.display.Stage; 
import flash.display.StageAlign; 
import flash.display.StageScaleMode; 
import flash.events.Event; 

public class StageWebViewExample extends MovieClip{

    private var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();

    public function StageWebViewExample() 
    {

        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        webView.stage = this.stage;
        webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight );
        webView.loadURL( "http://www.google.com" );

        stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKey );
    }

    private function onKey( event:KeyboardEvent ):void
    {
        if( event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK && webView.isHistoryBackEnabled )
        {
            trace("Back.");
            webView.historyBack();
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        if( event.keyCode == Keyboard.SEARCH && webView.isHistoryForwardEnabled )
        {
            trace("Forward.");
            webView.historyForward();
        }
    }
   }
 }
```