# Adobe Flash - Air application - Webview

Tags: actionscript, air, adobe

I would like to display a webpage in my air application upon the app opening.

I have been searching for an example but have not found one. Can anyone provide sudo code or an example?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: For how to use `StageWebView`, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202143/how-to-work-with-air-3-2-and-htmlloader/27202456#27209939).

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/quick_start_as/quickstarts/qs_using_stage_web_view.html

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. here is the actionscript for anyone else who has this same problem:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.display.Stage; 
import flash.display.StageAlign; 
import flash.display.StageScaleMode; 
import flash.events.Event;

var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();


webView.stage = this.stage;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight );

webView.loadURL( "http://www.google.com" );
```